# Cannot understand why random number algorithms give different results

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to understand why the following 2 code snippets lead to different output and I'm hoping someone can enlighten me. The second version is marginally faster - which is my motivation since this all sits in a loop, but I need to know if it is equivalent and if not then why ?

```
    things <- 100000
    n.events <- 3
    probs <- rep(0.05, n.events)

    # Method 1
    set.seed(1)
    events1 <- matrix(n.events, nrow=things)
    events1 <- sapply(probs, function(probs) rbinom(things,1,probs))

    # Method 2
    set.seed(1)
    events2 <- matrix( rbinom(things*n.events, 1, probs), ncol=n.events,    byrow=TRUE)

    > identical(events1, events2)
    [1] FALSE
```

Comment: `set.seed(1); events2 <- matrix( rbinom(things*n.events, 1, probs), ncol=n.events,    byrow=FALSE);  identical(events1, events2) # TRUE`........

Comment: @CathG, post as answer (with some more explanation)?

Comment: np. Following @BenBolker advice, I'm posting it as answer if you think it's worth it ?

Comment: Yes go for it please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the same result, you need to put `byrow=FALSE` instead of `byrow=TRUE` for the second option.

the first way you're computing the random matrix, it computes `rbinom(things,1,probs)` `length(probs)` times, obtaining each time a `things` long vector.

To obtain the exact same matrix with the second way, which computes a `length(probs)`*`things` long vector, you need to "organize" it in `length(probs)` vectors of length `things`.

(either way, seed is "treated" exactly the same "in between" the computations so the numbers obtained are the same)

**EDIT**

If you want to use different values for the vector `probs`, you need to compute `events2` in a way that the probs are used in the same "order" than for `events1` so first the first value of vector probs, until the desired length is reached, then the second value, etc. and then, organize the columns of your matrix the same way as before, so using `byrow=FALSE`.

***Example***

```
# define the parameters:
things <- 100000
n.events <- 3
probs <- c(0.05, 0.01, 0.20)

# compute the random vectors with sapply
set.seed(1)
events1 <- sapply(probs, function(probs) rbinom(things,1,probs))

# compute the random vectors "directly", using the "right" probs
set.seed(1)
events2 <- matrix(rbinom(things*n.events, 1, rep(probs, e=things)), ncol=n.events,    byrow=FALSE)

# check the results
identical(events1, events2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Actually - I have found a problem. This works when all the probs are equivalent - but not if they are different. Example if you set `probs <- c(0.05, 0.01, 0.20)` and then run the code using method 2 with `byrows=FALSE` - you do not get events in columns in those proportions and instead the odds are equal. If you set `byrows=TRUE` the identical test is still false, but at least you get the correct proportions in each column. It seem as though something is being shuffled somewhere with `byrows=FALSE`. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user2498193, as stated in the help of `rbinom`: "The numerical arguments other than n are recycled to the length of the result" so the `prob` argument is recycled until it reaches the desired length but it is recycled as `c(probs, probs, probs, ...)` so, let's say `probs=c(p1, p2, p3)`, first p1 is used, then p2, then p3, then p1 again, whereas, for `events1`, it's p1, p1, p1, etc. and then p2, p2, etc. . After each computation, the seed is changed, so, on order to have `events2` identical to `events1` you must compute the random vector using p1, p1, p1, ... and then p2, p2,etc. I'll edit.