# Correct way to generate parallel random booleans

Tags: r, random, parallel-processing

Following on from this q ([Cannot understand why random number algorithms give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805012/cannot-understand-why-random-number-algorithms-give-different-results)), I have some code simulating random booleans. Because I wish to do this ALOT and fast, I wish to wrap this in a function like so:

```
# setup external to function
number <- 5
probs <- rep(0.1, 5)

# core function
event.sim <- function(var, things){
    mod.probs <- probs * var
    events <- matrix(rbinom(things*number, 1, probs), ncol=number, byrow=FALSE)
    av.events <- max(rowSums(events))
    return(av.events)
}

library("parallel")
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterExport(cl, c("event.sim", "probs", "number"))
test <- clusterMap(cl, event.sim, var=df1$var1, things=df1$things, SIMPLIFY=TRUE)
stopCluster(cl)
```

and parallelize it using `clusterMap()` from `parallel`. Now this is no problem and I have this working, however I am concerned that by executing in parallel, my booleans are not sufficiently "random" anymore. I can find alot of info online about generating random numbers in parallel, but they all seem to describe generating lots of random numbers at once, and I can't relate that to my function that draws relatively few random booleans each time it is run. Have I problem here and do I need to do something differently?

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is not "sufficiently random" anymore?  If it's that parallel threads on the same machine can produce identical random numbers (which I suspect is unlikely) then you can randomly create a set of seeds and feed a different seed to each of your worker threads.

Comment: [Package 'parallel' vignette](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) (Section 6)

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens - I don't have hard evidence but everything I'm reading says be really careful with parellel RNG - therefore I am being careful :). @Roland - thanks that is helpful, although I don't fully understand where the `nextRNGStream(s)` command shoudl be used in my example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `clusterSetRNGStream(cl)` after creating your cluster and before running your function.

Comment: Thanks @Nick K - yes I stumbled onto that after I could not figure out the vignette example Roland directed me to.